# Find the remainder of $\frac{2^{2014}}{7}$

Tags: modular-arithmetic

> Find the remainder of $\dfrac{2^{2014}}{7}$

I am new to the modular arithmetic, Any suggestions to solve this question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As $2^3\equiv1\pmod7$ and $2014\equiv1\pmod3$

$\implies2^{2014}\equiv2^1\pmod7$

Comment: What is the remainder the OP asked for ?.

Comment: @Felix, I think so as OP has accepted the answer

Comment: $= 2$. Thanks. $\left(\bullet\quad\bullet \atop {\mid \atop \smile}\right)$